# How does impl and traits work on a lower level?

Tags: compiler-construction, rust

I'm kind of interested in working on the rust compiler one day, but I want to have a solid understanding of how everything is implemented in Rust. I understand most of the concepts in Rust, or how they would be implemented. However, I'm not too sure about impl's or traits are implemented at a lower level? For instance, what kind of code they would generate, etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is quite unspecific (and an exhaustive answer would be excruciating to read), so I'll just refer you to two things:

The [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) can show generated LLVM IR and assembly.

The [Rust source code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/) is publicly available. The code you seek lives in librustc (which takes the AST from libsyntax, typechecked by `librustc_typeck` and borrow-checked by `librustc_borrowck` and drives LLVM byte code creation). The [README.md](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/librustc/README.md) of librustc has a lot of info for you.